# How can you rewrite the estimand in terms of propensity scores? Dowhy question

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, causal-diagram

I am going through the backdoor criterion and how we get from an expression involving **do** to one which doesn't as below.

[image]

What i don't quite get is how to rewrite this estimand in terms of propensity scores. e.g. imagine we denote this propensity score by e(v2) - i get that the propensity score acts as a mediator between our v2 variable and drug, but what i don't get is how this statistical estimand on right hand side can be rewritten in terms of propensity scores. All i can think is that P(drug | v2) = e(v2).

Is there a way to rewrite this estimand in terms of propensity scores? Trying to understand formula against prop scores.

Comment: The point of the propensity score is to write an estimand *without* a propensity score. In your case, the estimand is $P(cancer | do(drug))$ but the estimator can be the $\hat{\beta_1}$ from the $t$-test using weights or matching for the propensity score.

Comment: i see, so because we don't have those individual probabilities e.g. p(v2) etc, another way to estimate it is to just use propensity score.

Comment: Hmm, not quite. Or rather that's not how *I* see it. The propensity isn't what we want to measure, in fact we don't care what the propensity is; it's a nuisance parameter. For that reason we don't write the propensity in the estimand. The true estimand is the counterfactual - we care about for a given individual, their average treatment effect. The fact that there's confounding by indication, that some subjects are more likely to receive drug, means we have to adjust it.

Comment: so the equation on right hand side is the statistical estimand, i thougt the whole point of identification step from judea pearls dowhy was to first get that statistical estimand. Then we 'estimate' using a whole host of estimation methods, one is propensity scores so i was confused as to how to get from statisical estimand to a formula involving propensioty scores.  i understand that the propensity scores act as a mediator between v2 and drug .

Comment: Can you please define "v2"? In fact, for the causal model you drew, "v2" is not a confounder at all. So appealing to it does not change or modify our understanding of an estimand.

Comment: v2 was initally pointing to drug - i removed the edge as per judea pearls backdoor criterion. what i am showing is the interventional graph.

Comment: It's totally unclear to me how you are applying a conceptual model to define an estimand versus applying a conceptual model to propose an estimator. Someone else may be able to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The casual estimand is $E[Y|do(a)]$. When the backdoor criterion is satisfied, we have that $E[Y|do(a)] = E[E[Y|A=a, X]]$, where $X$ is a sufficient adjustment set. The propensity score theorem says that $E[E[Y|A=a, X]] = E[E[Y|A=a, p(X)]]$, where $p(X) = P(A|X)$ is the propensity score. This last step is what allows us to estimate the causal estimand using propensity score methods.